# An exception occurred during a WebClient request (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy a directory folder from our HTTP server using Powershell, I would like to copy it's entire contents including subfolders into the local drive of my current server. This is the code I have

```
$source = "http://servername/serverupdates/deploy/Program%20Files/"
$destination = "C:\Program Files"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

When I run the script in Powershell ISE as admin, I get the error message

> "Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

Any suggestions on what could be going on?

Comment: Is that URL really reachable via http? (And even if it is, are you really sure you want to use http and not https?)

Comment: Yes it's reachable, I tested it first and copied the URL directly from IE into Powershell. The only reason why its HTTP and not HTTPS is because that's how it was in the URL.

Comment: You might not have write access to c:\program files by default, it’s often restricted. Tried writing it somewhere else?

Comment: @MarkWragg Tried, didn't work. I read online somewhere that the DownloadFile requires a filetype not a directory type so something like documents.zip but my job requires it to be in the Program Files folder so I can't make a zip. I don't know how to make it a directory type. Also since I'm doing this to make our server deployment automated, having to unzip a folder each time they deploy would be a pain.

Comment: You should consider a package management solution.

Comment: I haven't heard of that, could I just google that + powershell and it will tell me what to do? Or is it something more specific I should google to handle what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you to do something like this.

wget.exe --mirror --no-parent  'http://servername/serverupdates/deploy/Program%20Files/' -P 'C:\Program Files'

Note: not tested

Comment: I've never used wget before, my work wants all of this in Powershell since they plan on using it to automate our server build process. It's unfortunate but the way they want it. Is there something similar for Powershell?